# Ionic: Why are my form controls getting removed from the DOM upon selection?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a page where I can manage users. When I click on any given user, a modal comes up and has several form inputs including a select.

Everything is working properly, data is getting saved/updated correctly. What I am seeing though is when I make a selection, the form element is removed from the dom.

For example, if I choose the select to change a role, when I click "OK", the input disappears.

Here is my `.ts` file:

```
private myForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        userId: ['', Validators.required],
        bar: [''],
        baz: ['']
    });
}
```

Here is my `.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="save()" novalidate>
    ...

    <ion-item *ngIf="employees.length > 0">
        <ion-label stacked>Employee</ion-label>
        <ion-select formControlName="userId" [(ngModel)]="employees" placeholder="Select">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee.id">
          {{ employee.firstName }} {{ employee.lastName }}
            </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    ...
</form>
```

In my example above, everything is getting saved correctly. When I choose an employee, when I click "OK" to select it, the `<ion-item>` is completely removed from the DOM.

I'm not sure what I'm doing to cause that to happen. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: The *ngIf is a strong clue. You didn't show us what happens in save(). The array gets emptied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: Your *ngModel* on ion-select is the array of employees. That means if you select something you set

> employees = *employeeSelectedViaSelect*.id

. This changes the array to an id which probably hasn't a length-property. So your

> *ngIf="employees.length > 0"

is false now, so the ion-item gets removed.

You're probably better off with something like this:

> ```
> <ion-item *ngIf="employees.length > 0">
>     <ion-label stacked>Employee</ion-label>
>     <ion-select formControlName="userId" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployeeId" placeholder="Select">
>         <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee.id">
>       {{ employee.firstName }} {{ employee.lastName }}
>         </ion-option>
>     </ion-select>
> </ion-item>
> ```

(Only thing i changed is the ngModel to a variable which holds the ID of the currently selected employee.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Your explanation makes perfect sense. I wanted to include everything within the `ngIf` since I may not always have employees available. 

Thank you for your help!